# Displaying recent items in boxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I am trying to display details from my MYSQL db into these boxes, the last 3 entries in my db, how could i echo this?

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
              <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="span3">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h3>Thumbnail</h3>
                      <p>Description 1/p>
                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="span3">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" >
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                      <p>Desc 2.</p>
                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP/mysql code?

Comment: I just need to know how to echo into the thumbnail label for example the last title of the entry. I know im being vague, but the DB structure is as follows.   id  title  organization  desccription  time  lat  long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any code at all, the basic idea is as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
        <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></p>
                    <p> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Action</a>  <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You read my mind, although my description was very week. It was exactly what I needed! Thank you!